$f_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$. $\phi_A(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$. $f_A(x)/\phi_(x)$ has some property. (Ichiro Satake.)
I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.
I want to know how to prove the fact that the author wrote in Remark below.
My attempt:

$f_A(x)E=(xE-A)B(x)=(xE-A)\psi(x)B'(x)$.
$\phi_A(x)E=(xE-A)B^*(x)$.
I want to prove $B'(x)=B^*(x)$.


THEOREM 1. If $f_A(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^{n-i}$ is the characteristic polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$, one has $$f_A(A)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i A^{n-i}=0.$$


Proof. Let $\Delta_{ij}$ be the $(i,j)$-cofactor of $xE-A$. It is easily seen that $\Delta_{ij}$ is a polynomial whose degree is at most $n-1$. If we put $\Delta_{ij}=b_{ij,0}x^{n-1}+b_{ij,1}x^{n-2}+\cdots+b_{ij,n-1}$, and $B_k=(b_{ij,k})^T$, then we have $$\det(xE-A)\cdot E=(xE-A)(x^{n-1}B_0+x^{n-2}B_1+\cdots+B_{n-1})\\=(x^{n-1}B_0+x^{n-2}B_1+\cdots+B_{n-1})(xE-A).$$
Thus $B_0,B_1,\dots,B_{n-1}$ commute with $A$. Hence substituting the matrix $A$ for the variable $x$, we obtain $$f_A(A)=(A-A)(B_0A^{n-1}+B_1A^{n-2}+\cdots+B_{n-1})=0.$$

Let $\phi_A(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Since $f_A(A)=0$ by Theorem 1, the characteristic polynomial $f_A(x)$ is divisible by $\phi_A(x)$. In particular, the degree of $\phi_A(x)$ is at most $n$. On the other hand, if $\alpha$ is any eigenvalue of $A$, $\phi_A(x)$ is divisible by $x-\alpha$. In fact, let us denote by $x$ an eigenvector ($\neq 0$) belonging to $\alpha$; then $Ax=\alpha x$ implies $\phi_A(A)x=\phi_A(\alpha)x=0$. Therefore $\phi_A(\alpha)=0$. Thus, the roots of the minimal polynomial $\phi_A(x)$ coincide with the eigenvalues (disregarding multiplicity). [An alternative proof: $\phi_A(A)=0$ implies that $\phi_A(x)$ is divisible by $xE-A$ as a polynomial with matrix coefficients: $\phi_A(x)E=(xE-A)B^*(x)$. Taking the determinants of both sides, we get $\phi_A(x)^n=\det(xE-A)\det B^*(x)=f_A(x)\det B^*(x)$. Therefore, $\phi_A(x)^n$ is divisible by $f_A(x)$, whence follows our assertion.]


Remark. If $\psi(x)$ denotes the greatest common divisor (as a polynomial in $x$) of $n^2$ components of $B(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^{n-i-1} B_i$ in the notation of the proof of Theorem 1, then it can be shown that $B^*(x)=B(x)/\psi(x)$, i.e. $\phi_A(x)=f_A(x)/\psi(x)$.


This was explained in MacDuffee, Vectors and Matrices, pp.78-79. The function $\psi(x)$ here corresponds to the suppement $\operatorname{sup}(Ix-A)$ in MacDuffee.

@user1551 thank you very much for your answer. I will read the link. Thank you!

user1551, thank you very much for your answer.
I have read pp.78-79 in "Vectors and Matrices" by Cyrus Colton MacDuffee.
$f_A(x)\cdot E=(xE-A)\cdot B(x)$.
If the elements of $B(x)$ have a greatest common divisor of degree $>0$, this polynomial will be a divisor of every element of the right member of the above equation and will therefore be a divisor of $f_A(x)$. We shall venture to define the quotient of $B(x)$ by that greatest common divisor of its elements whose leading coefficient is $1$ as the supplement of $xE-A$, and to write it as $\sup (xE-A)$. Its elements are relatively prime polynomials in $x$, and it satisfies an equation $$(xE-A)\cdot \sup (xE-A)=h(x)\cdot E$$ where $h(x)$ is a divisor of the characteristic polynomial $f_A(x)$ and has $1$ as its leading coefficient.
MacDuffee proved the following theorem holds on pp.78-79 in the book.
THEOREM 41. The polynomial $h(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$.
By Theorem 41, $(xE-A)\cdot \sup (xE-A)=\phi_A(x)\cdot E$.
And $\phi_A(x)\cdot E=(xE-A)\cdot B^*(x)$.
So, $(xE-A)\cdot B^*(x)=(xE-A)\cdot \sup (xE-A)$.
Since $xE-A$ is non-singular, $B^*(x)=\sup (xE-A)$.
So, $B^*(x)=B(x)/\psi(x)$.
